# Using Moq to test a method that takes a struct

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the following method that needs to be tested

```
public class S2SJwtGenerator : BaseJwtGenerator, IS2SJwtGenerator
{
    public S2SJwtGenerator();
    public string Generate(string tenantId, string username, TimeSpan lifetime);
}
```

I need to mock Generate.

```
protected readonly Mock<S2SJwtGenerator> tokenGen = new Mock<S2SJwtGenerator>();

var ts = new TimeSpan(1,1,1);

tokenGen.Setup(x => x.Generate(_testTenantId,null, ts)).Returns("NEWTOKEN");
```

I am constantly getting notSupported error.

I tried using

```
tokenGen.Setup(x => x.Generate(_testTenantId,null, It.Ref<TimeSpan>.IsAny)).Returns("NEWTOKEN");
```

I still get not supported. `TimeSpan` is a struct. How do I get this to work

Comment: You need to mock the interface, not the implementation: `new Mock<IS2SJwtGenerator>()`

Comment: Could you please share with us the exact exception messages?

Comment: BTW why don't you simply use `It.IsAny<TimeSpan>()`?